# How to join tables in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am new to Laravel, I have a question regarding Eloquent:

This is my DB table structure:

```
users
- id
- user_id
- username
- name
- email
- password
- email_verified_at
- remember_tok
- created_at
- updated_at

challenges
- id
- challenge_id
- category_id
- hashtag
- title
- description
- duration
- link
- created_at
- updated_at
- user_id

user_challenges
- user_id
- challenge_id
- duration
- created_at
- updated_at
```

What I want to achieve is to display the user's challenges, so for example, if a user joins a challenge in the user dashboard I want to display the challenges that he joined, but also the challenges that the user has created (if he has created any);

**Models\User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    public function challenges() {
        return $this->hasMany(Challenge::class, 'user_id');
    }

    public function userChallenges() {
        return $this->hasMany(UserChallenge::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Models\Challenge.php**

```
class Challenge extends Model
{
    public function user () {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

**Models\UserChallenge.php**

```
class UserChallenge extends Model
{
    public function user () {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my Home Controller:
**App\Http\Controllers\HomeController.php**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $user_id = auth()->id();
        $user = User::find($user_id);

        return view('home')
            ->with('challenges', $user->challenges)
            ->with('userChallenges', $user->userChallenges);
    }
}
```

This is what I get currently for the "Joined Challenges" in My Dashboard - but how can I join the tables when returning the view so I can also get the challenge hashtag title? Like I get above under "My Challenges" section?
[Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpOlm.png)

**UPDATE**:
What should I add to my database so I can count the number of users that have joined the challenge?

Comment: I think a [Many to Many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is what you're looking for, to link users and the chanllenges they've joined. This will help you solve both the issues you're currently facing

Comment: Select id's for $user->challenges and $user->userChallanges, make an array of all id's, strip duplicates, requery DB  whereIn(unique ids).

Comment: @nikistag could you provide me with a code?

Comment: @ArunAS yes I know that it is Many to Many Relationship I just couldn't figure out on how to implement it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get user created challenges, I believe you are already doing it correctly.

And to get user joined challenges. You almost get it right with your pivot table. You can have look on [many-to-many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) in laravel documentation.

These are the sample code to retrieve challenges created by a user and challenges joined by a user. These code should reside in your User Model, you should keep the model.

```
public function created_challenges()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Challenge::class,'user_id','id');
}

public function joined_challenges()
{
     return $this->belongsToMany(Challenges::class, 'user_challenges', 'user_id', 'challenges_id');
}
```

Once you get the relationship working right, you can simply use the collection returned from the relationship. Once you pass the `$user->joined_challenges` to your view, you can do as below

```
@foreach ($joined_challenges as $challenge)
    <p>{{$challenge->hashtag}}</p>   
    <p>{{$challenge->title}}</p>   
@endforeach
```

Let me know it this works, cheers! ;)

Comment: I added this line of code but it doesn't work - I get this error: "Class 'App\Challenges' not found" - I added 'App\Challenges' in the User Model but it didn't work then I get the maximum execution timeout error..

Comment: I need to receive both, the challenges that the user has created which I am currently getting them as you can see in the screenshot above in the post, and the challenges that the user has currently joined which I am also getting them but I am getting only the id of the user and the challenge and I would like to get the other information as well from the challenges table

Comment: Okay sorry there was a mistake (it is Challenge and not Challenges), now it works fine but I a still not sure how to get the title, hashtag of the joined challenge?

Comment: And also with this, since I get everything I need - I don't need the UserModel, right?

Comment: I have updated the answer, please have a look and let me know if that works. If it does, could you accept my answer? Thanks! :)

Comment: I have one question for you - of course, if you know - What is the best way to keep track of how many people have joined the challenge? I want to display the number of people who have joined the challenge;

Comment: You can create a `hasMany` relationship in your `Challenge` class, which will return you with a collection of `user_challenges` given a user record. With that, just use collection's `count()` function and you will get the result ;)

Comment: Well I cannot retrieve data from user_challenges, because the user_challenges table keeps track of the users and the challenges they joined, what I want to achieve is to display how many users have joined every challenge. So, for instance Challenge A has been joined by 200 users, Challenge B by 120 users, and so on. Once the user clicks on complete challenge the challenge will be removed from the user_challenges table as it is no longer joined by that user.

Comment: In this case I would suggest you have a look on soft delete where you can refer on https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#querying-soft-deleted-models.  In this case, if you want to get the count of total participants for all challenges you can just use `->withTrashed()`, and to get currently active participants, you can query normally. And to get completed participation, you can use `->onlyTrashed()`

Comment: The thing is that I need to keep track on every "Join" click - because some user may join a challenge and after the challenge duration expires then he may click on delete challenge and that challenge will no longer be in the `user_challenges` table - so how exactly should I use the soft delete models?

Comment: With the soft deleted model wouldn't I just grow my database unnecessarily?

Comment: We usually worry about growing database due to query speed. With soft delete scope, it minimizes the impact to querying speed (that you won't notify). And storage is usually less of a concern except if you have a really really large table.

Comment: Okay sounds good - so instead of deleting records from my `user_challenges` table I should do soft delete, right?

Comment: Hello, I have updated the `user_challenges` table and added 2 new columns: status, deleted_at - which are not present in the `challenges` table, when displaying the data in my blade view I can access only those columns which are the same for both tables `user_challenges` and `challenges`, how can I access those columns and plus the new columns that I added in the `user_challenges` table? Thank you.

Comment: You can simply add the `withPivot('columnName')`, and then get the column using `$model->pivot->columnName`